# Avro Schema format Exception - “SecurityClassification” is not a defined name

Tags: json, avro, avro-tools

I'm trying to use this avro schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ComplianceEntity",
  "namespace": "com.linkedin.events.metadata",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "fieldPath",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "complianceDataType",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "ComplianceDataType",

        "symbols": [
          "NONE",
          "MEMBER_ID"
        ],
        "symbolDocs": {
          "NONE": "None of the following types apply",
          "MEMBER_ID": "ID for LinkedIn members"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "complianceDataTypeUrn",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "fieldFormat",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "enum",
          "name": "FieldFormat",
          "symbols": [
            "NUMERIC"
          ],
          "symbolDocs": {
            "NUMERIC": "Numerical format, 12345"
          },
          "doc": "The field format"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "securityClassification",
      "type": "SecurityClassification"
    },
    {
      "name": "valuePattern",
      "default": null,
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To generate and avro file using the avro-tools:

```
java -jar ./avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema ComplianceEntity.avsc .
```

But I am getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "SecurityClassification" is not a defined name. The type of the "securityClassification" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.

Could anyone tell, why SecurityClassification is not identified as a defined name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it as type of your field, however you are not defining it properly like for `complianceDataType`, that's the reason why you are getting the avro exception

```
{
      "name": "securityClassification",
      "type": "SecurityClassification"
}
```

Make sure that if you have more than 1 Schema, you pass all of them, especially dependency schemas. It is supported from AVRO 1.5.3 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-877.

```
java -jar ./avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema SecurityClassification.avsc ComplianceEntity.avsc .
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but I am already having SecurityClassification.avsc schema

Comment: updating answer, @BhargavTeja